# angular-ui-grid: empty viewport with single filter

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using a Filter similar to this one: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/321_singleFilter

But I've found a visual problem. This problem is reproducible on the tutorial page above:

1. Scroll down to the bottom
2. Enter a 'C' into the filters input field
3. Click filter button
4. Remove the 'C' from the filters input field
5. Click fliter button

Now you see an empty grid.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should open an Issue on the github page of the project https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues

Comment: I've found a similar issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5988.